# Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a5751969/public_html/func/user.func.php on line 9

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have looked through the code so many time and rewritten it and still can't figure out how to fix the error.

There are lines 6-10;

```
function login_check ($email, $password) {
$email = mysql_real_escape_string ($email);
$login_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) as `count`,`user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$email' AND `password`='".md5($password)."'");
return (mysql_result($login_query, 0) == 1) ? mysql_result($login_query, 0, 'user_id') : false;
```

}

Re-written code;

```
function login_check ($email, $password) {
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $login_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) as `count`, `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$email' AND `password`='".md5($password)."'");
    return (mysql_result($login_query, 0) == 1) ? mysql_result($login_query, 0, 'user_id') : false; 
}
```

Comment: This occurs because your mysql_query is throwing an error.  You'll need to debug using `mysql_error`.

Comment: fyi: mysql has a `password` function you can use instead of `md5`. I'm not sure if it's any different, but just something to consider.

Comment: @corsiKa `The PASSWORD() function is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should not use it in your own applications. For that purpose, consider MD5() or SHA1() instead.`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password

Comment: @mazzucci Well, that's good to know. Interesting. Thanks for that!

Comment: I rewrote the code, again, and it now works, I will have a look into what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a GROUP BY clause on your SQL statement.

```
"SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) as `count`,`user_id` 
    FROM `users` 
    WHERE `email`='$email' 
        AND `password`='".md5($password)."'
    GROUP BY `user_id`"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an error due to the arguments passed. I can think of couple of solutions here.
1. Echo the arguments before passing it to the query.
2. Also try the SQL query on MySQL and see if you are getting your desired result.